# SQL: IF oder CASE with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, case

I have this table:

```
DATUM,Customer_ID,Block_TYPE
'2019-01-21','00027096',NULL
'2019-01-21','00027096','big'
'2019-03-06','00573618','small'
'2019-03-06','00573618',NULL
'2020-01-01';'00027513',NULL
```

I want to create a new table with one line per client, where the values ​​of the Block_Type column have priorities:

1. if it has the value big, then short,
2. if it is small, then small,
3. finally, if it is null, then null

I tried to do it, but i get the same value for all customer :(

```sql
SELECT Datum, Customer_ID, 
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (select Block_TYPE from MyTable where Block_TYPE = 'big') THEN 'big'
        WHEN EXISTS (select Block_TYPE from MyTable where Block_TYPE = 'small') THEN 'small'
        ELSE Null 
    END AS Decision
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

No sub-query needed:

```
SELECT Datum, Customer_ID, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Block_TYPE = 'big' THEN 'short'
         WHEN Block_TYPE = 'small' THEN 'small'
         ELSE Null 
       END AS Decision
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a new table with one line per client, where the values ​​of the Block_Type column have priorities:

You can use aggregation as the customer level:

```
select customer_id,
       (case when sum(case when type = 'big' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'small'
             else max(type)
        end) as overall_type 
from mytable
group by customer_id
```